# Facebook graph : posts not being shown to Facebook Page Fans

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook graph API to post message to my facebook page.
But posts are not showned to fan users, only showned to my facebook admin account.

This is my Python code:

```
graph =facebook.GraphAPI(access_token="xxxx")
graph.put_object("me", "feed", message=msg)
```

Perhaps my posts are not public? Should I add this kind of instruction: `publish = true`
My Facebook app is in developer mode? Should I switch it on production mode?
Thanks a lot.
Théo.

Comment: Finally after verification, posts are well in Public status. Facebook graph works fine and publishs posts in Public status.

Comment: But posts are yet not showned to users fan page....